# validateDOMNesting(...): <button> Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a website using React.

When my website has lots of text, I'll show a button such as `show more or less`.

In my project, It works well, but always show a warning about `validateDOMNesting(...): <button>`

My sample code like this.

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

function handleShow() {
  show ? setShow(false) : setShow(true);
}

<CardActionArea>
  <Button onClick={handleShow}> 
    { show ? text : text.substr(0, 100) + "..." }
  </Button>
</CardActionArea>
```

I think `CardActionArea` is a `button` component, it makes a nested `button` now.

But if I declare `href` property in `button`, it doesn't make a warning.

Is there a good way that doesn't make a warning not using `href` property?

Comment: Can you recreate the warning in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq) with a minimal example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Issue:** With your code you've placed a button within a button which is a no-no.

From the Material-UI CardActionArea [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/#inheritance)

> ## Inheritance
>
> The props of the `ButtonBase` component are also available. You can take
>   advantage of this behavior to target nested components.

And if you cruise on over to the [ButtonBase](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/#component-name) docs you'll see it is by default a `'button'` component.

[image]

**Option 1:** Move button logic to `CardActionArea` and set the `component` prop of the `Button` to anything *not* a button, like a span. This makes the entire card action area have the onClick handler and responsive.

```
<CardActionArea onClick={handleShow}>
  <Button component="span"> 
    { show ? text : text.substr(0, 100) + "..." }
  </Button>
</CardActionArea>
```

**Option 2:** Keep as-is and set the component prop of the `CardActionArea` to *anything other* than 'button'. This will leave *only* the button with the onClick handler, the card action area will register clicks, i.e. the ripple effect, but will by unresponsive otherwise.

```
<CardActionArea component="span">
  <Button onClick={handleShow}> 
    { show ? text : text.substr(0, 100) + "..." }
  </Button>
</CardActionArea>
```

[image: Edit Button within CardActionArea]

Between the two *option 1* is, IMO, the preferred option as it makes the entire action area responsive, but this is based entirely on only the facts presented and your needs/design could be different or more complex.

Comment: Hi, It works really well. Really thanks for your help. Can I ask one more?. 
In my code, there are many things in CardActionArea, So I can't put in onClick option in CardActionArea. 
Can I ask why you put onClick in CardActionArea, not in Button? 
In my case, it works well, although I put all things onClick and component="span" in Button.

Comment: @mimic Sure. With *just* a single button it felt "odd" to me that the entire action area appeared to be "interactable", i.e. the visual "haptic" feedback ripple effect, but *only* the actual button did anything. But this is also why I added my note at the end about the options and not knowing much of your specific scenario and usage.

Comment: Really, thanks for your help. As I mentioned before, I did many things in CardActionArea besides Button. Really thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint you should keep the "action" with the element that can initiate it. For example, those using screen readers or otherwise navigating your page (visually impaired) may not understand that they can interact with a span, as that doesn't make any sense in that context. If you do this, ensure you use appropriate ARIA attributes to address any accessibility needs.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the hover ripple effect on the CardActionArea when hovering the button inside it?

Comment: @SimonTran There's a `disableRipple` prop for the button, but I think you are asking about the hover highlighting instead. You could override some CSS to disable the button's hover styling, or it seems using the `fullWidth` prop on the `Button` makes it so you only over it and don't see the "double-hovering" effect (*well, you do, but it's applied across the entire width, same as the card action area*). If the *slightly* darker hover style bothers you then go with the first option I suggested and override some CSS rules.